# Evaluating 2 limits to infinity

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following limits:
1. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^n+9n}{6^n+3n}$.
Lets re-write this a little. We can do this by writing
\begin{equation*}
\frac{3^n+9n}{6^n+3n} = \frac{\left(e^{\ln{(3)}}\right)^n+9n}{\left(e^{\ln{(6)}}\right)^n+3n} = \frac{e^{n\ln{(3)}}+9n}{e^{n\ln{(6)}}+3n}.
\end{equation*}
Now we have a limit of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so we can apply L'Hopital's rule which gives
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{3^n+9n}{6^n+3n}\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e^{n\ln{(3)}}+9n}{e^{n\ln{(6)}}+3n}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\ln{(3)}e^{n\ln{(3)}}+9}{\ln{(6)}e^{n\ln{(6)}}+3}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{(\ln{(3)})^2e^{n\ln{(3)}}}{(\ln{(6)})^2e^{n\ln{(6)}}}\right) \\
&= 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
since the denominator is much larger than the numerator as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\right)$.
So the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ but not sure how to start it.

Some help would be great!!!

Comment: You are asking too many questions of the same type but I don't see your effort to solve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is less than 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac36\right)^n+\frac{9n}{6^n}=0.$$

Second one is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}n}=\frac12.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For the first one, how did you get $\frac{9n}{6^n}$?

Comment: @squenshl I note that $\frac{3^n+9n}{6^n+3n}\le \frac{3^n+9n}{6^n}$ since $6^n+3n\geq 6^n$ when $n\geq 0$

Comment: Gotcha thank you!! My solution was different (see above) but I get what you are going!!!

Comment: @squenshl You‘re welcome 

Answer (score 1):

A. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^n+9n}{6^n+3n}$

Use l'hopital rule. so $\frac{ln(3)3^{n}+9}{ln(6)6^{n}+3}$. The constants have no effect and you can write $6^n$ as $3^{1.63}$ and it should be clear that the limit approaches $0$ (if you show some work and tell me where you are stuck, I will explain more)

B.
Multiply by the conjugate and get $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}+n}$ and note that its equal to $\frac{n}{n+n}$

Comment: How is that equal to $\frac{n}{n+n}$?

Comment: @squenshi it’s because as $n$ goes to infinity, $n=n+1$ and square root of $n^2$ is $n$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Divide throughout by $3^n$ and note that $p(x)/a^x\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$ for any polynomial $p(x)$ and $a>1.$

(2) Pull out $n^2$ from under the $\sqrt{}$ symbol. And write as a fraction with $n$ in the numerator and the reciprocal of the difference in the denominator. Now apply L'hopital.